# negative results of reduction between 12AM and 6AM

Tags: c#

I tried to do a 2-date reduction to find the difference in minutes.

this is my code

```
DateTime expDate = DateTime.ParseExact(stringExpDate, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


                    Console.WriteLine("date now:" + DateTime.Now);
                    Console.WriteLine("date exp:" + expDate);


                    TimeSpan expCount = expDate - DateTime.Now;
                    var expMinute = (int)expCount.TotalMinutes;
                    // var expMinute = expDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes;//got the same results as above

                    Console.WriteLine("exp count:" + expCount);
                    Console.WriteLine("exp min:" + expMinute);
```

the results i got

date now:1/7/2019 6:31:32 AM

date exp:1/7/2019 12:00:00 AM

exp count:-06:31:32.5165326

exp min:-391

why produce negative values?
shouldn't it be positive?

Comment: 1/7/2019 12:00:00 AM is basically the start of the day (midnight). It's not noon. That would be 1/7/2019 12:00:00 PM

Comment: The explanation can be easily found in the documentation, you may want to try that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i have already tried substract you can look at in the code above.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i don't understand why its marked as duplicate as on the previous thread the nextDay (1998, 6, 3) is smaller than previousDay (1998, 6, 31). but on my problem expired date is 12AM, bigger than datetime.now that is 6AM

Comment: Are you completely sure that 0000 is higher/bigger than 0600? Because that's not correct. What you wanted to do is `TimeSpan expCount = DateTime.Date - expDate;`

Comment: its 1200 not 0000

Comment: No, that's 12PM, not AM. You are parsing a date, so it's always like if you were parsing `2019-01-01 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Your exp date is less than (earlier) than now so will produce a negative result. Do `DateTime.Now - exp` instead

Dates are like numbers, if today was a 6, yesterday would be 5 and tomorrow would be 7. Subtracting them follows similar math rules. Yesterday minus today is negative. Today minus yesterday is positive.

A simple date system is the unix one; the number of seconds that have passed since Jan 1, 1970. Here you can see they always count up, tomorrow's times will be larger numbers than today's times etc. This concept of numerical cal internal representation and particularly a date time being represented as "the number of intervals since some point in time" is very often used in various software; one of those things to remember and make use of.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now` is greater than the past date ([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netframework-4.7.2)), so you will have to write:

```
TimeSpan expCount = DateTime.Now - expDate;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZFNS8QwEIbv/RUhpxY3aetJXDxVkQUrQhc8p@2ogTZZkul@@Odr0m3RZSuuIYcwmXnmnXcqyyor@/5eIKxlCwT2G/8md2QK8RdhLDzsRYUhvU7SG5YmLEnpgtCDOyzPWV3TRUD@OsXBIrT8sdGlaOSnQKkVz7oGOwMr9ab5Sm2FkULhGIyWQTCLzbSyugH@aiTCk1QQ0tqLVnp3S8nVt/RnvXOQ/yDc/ANi9OFXCR5fbITyiZnuFP50zLUlbELM93eT@oRcqm5wO5QKo4nF1xpFc/yz8/VxfIYY@/GiK9H4bZ3YcMqM43eNBD@AWOG2bsA6yy0R7pZ6Cxfb7nqSykueTBv0X@65r2@lmqqP8qJl338B)

Comment: my datetime.now is smaller (6AM) than the expdate (12AM)

Comment: @aloisdg. never mind the OP, I already explained them their understanding is incorrect in the question

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan expCount = expDate - DateTime.Now;
```

`expDate` was at midnight. `Now` is 6 hours *later* on the same day. So the difference when you subtract a larger value from a smaller one is negative.

You can get your expected result like this:

```
TimeSpan expCount = DateTime.Now - expDate;
```

or like this:

```
TimeSpan expCount = (expDate - DateTime.Now).Duration;
```

Comment: my datetime.now 6AM smaller than the expdate 12AM

Comment: @herahadi 6am comes **after** 12am, and therefore is greater. Don't confuse 12am with 12pm, and don't believe just because you see a "12" that 12 must be greater than 6. When working with time of day, the 12am hour has an integer value of 0.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn "the 12am hour has an integer value of 0" this explains the problem.. thanks.